Commutation of Solutions of the Dirac Field
In page 53 of P&S, they derive equation 3.89, which is the commutator for the dirac field operators (the commutator is derived for pedagogic purposes),
$$[\psi(x), \psi^\dagger(y)] = \int \frac{d^3p d^3q}{(2\pi)^6} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p 2E_q}} e^{i(p \cdot x - q \cdot y)} \times
    \sum_{r,s} \left( [a_p^r, a_q^{s \dagger}] \bar{u}^r(p) u^s(q) + [b_p^r, b_q^{s \dagger}] \bar{v}^r(-p) v^s(-q) \right) \gamma^0$$
Knowing that the field operators are:
$$\psi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}} e^{ip \cdot x} \sum_{s=1,2} \left( a_p^s u^s(p) + b_{-p}^{s} v^s(-p) \right)$$
$$\psi^{\dagger}(y) = \int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_q}} e^{-iq \cdot y} \sum_{r=1,2} \left(  u^{r\dagger}(q)a_q^{r\dagger} +  v^{r\dagger}(-q)b_{-q}^{r\dagger} \right)$$
When calculating, I arrive to terms such as this:
$$[a_p^ra_q^{s\dagger}u^r(p)\bar{u}^s(q)-a_q^{s\dagger}a_p^r\bar{u}^s(q)u^r(p)]$$
Which should turn into:$[a_p^r,a_q^{s\dagger}]u^r(p)\bar{u}^s(q)$, which means that $u^r(p)\bar{u}^s(q)=\bar{u}^s(q)u^r(p)$, but that doesn't make any sense to me, since I've written those quantities down in terms of what they are ($u^r(p)=\left[\begin{matrix}\sqrt{p\cdot \sigma}\xi^r \\ \sqrt{p\cdot \bar{\sigma}}\xi^r\end{matrix}\right]$, $\bar{u}^s(q)=\left[\begin{matrix}\xi^{s\dagger}\sqrt{q\cdot \bar{\sigma}} & \xi^{s\dagger}\sqrt{q\cdot \sigma}\end{matrix}\right]$, and it doesn't appear to be equal.
So, what is the correct way to approach this? I've tried everything I could think of to understand this, since I don't want to take anything for granted as I go through the book.

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/825075/2451
